# iOS Maps - MapKit MKAnnotation with icon

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I'd like to create an MKAnnotation that looks exactly the same as the default, the only difference being that there will be an icon just to the left of the title.

Any advice here or code that will create this with an identical look and feel to the original?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that, by "title", you are referring to the callout of the annotation view, and by "icon" you mean the annotation view's image. (If I misunderstood your question, could you explain a little more what you mean by "icon" and "title"?)

You can move the callout position with respect to the position of the annotation view's image, as explained in the [documentation for MKAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **calloutOffset** The offset (in pixels) at which to place the callout bubble.
>
> @property (nonatomic) CGPoint calloutOffset
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This property
>   determines the additional distance by which to move the callout
>   bubble. When this property is set to (0, 0), the anchor point of the
>   callout bubble is placed on the top-center point of the annotation
>   view’s frame. Specifying positive offset values moves the callout
>   bubble down and to the right, while specifying negative values moves
>   it up and to the left.

You can also change the position of the image, and the documentation explains that too. However, the callout position is always set relative to the top-center point of the annotation view.s image.

It's a good idea to think of the "annotation view" as an instance of a class that has several properties and behaviors. The image can be a map pin, for example. The callout is also commonly called the information bubble, but formally, it's called the callout. I think the documentation is a little sloppy by using "annotation view" and "image" interchangeably. (In the reference to the annotation view's frame.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. You need to implement the delegate `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation`.

Here's some code to help you out.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation{
    static NSString *parkingAnnotationIdentifier=@"ParkingAnnotationIdentifier";

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotationClass class]])
    {
        //Try to get an unused annotation, similar to uitableviewcells
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView=[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:parkingAnnotationIdentifier];

        //If one isn't available, create a new one
        if(!annotationView)
        {
            annotationView=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:parkingAnnotationIdentifier];

            //Here's where the magic happens
            annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
        }
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Also [this](http://shawnsbits.com/blog/2011/04/12/custom-map-pins-for-mapkit/) might help